# Redirect in jQuery after finished download won't work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use [this](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) plugin in order to redirect the user to a success page when the download it's finished (I'm using `Django 1.5` and `HTML` templates to create the links).

This is the code:

```
<script src="/static/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/jquery.fileDownload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on("click", "#downloadbutton", function () {
         $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href')).done(function () {window.location.href = '/confirmation/download/{{ name }}';})
         });
</script>
```

and this is the cookie (in the download view):

```
response.set_cookie('fileDownload', 'True', path = '/file/download/'+down_file.name)
```

But when I hit the download button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: code edited, problem still the same**

Comment: Is this a typo: `$.fileDownload(.done` ??? Have you check your console? And what about reading plugin DOC?

Comment: use `window.location.href "http://stackoverflow.com";` instead of `window.location = '/confirmation/download/{{ name }}'`

Comment: This is not a Django question...

Answer (score -1):

Use this.

```
window.location.href = '/confirmation/download/{{ name }}';
```